# Why it shows error after uploading photo in rails app after I changed the storage to cloudinary with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

I have recently changed the cloud storage of image to cloudinary integrated with carrierrwave in my Rails app. It perfectly works but the problem is that it shows error that the photo is blank after uploading image. Even though it is showing error, I have manually reloaded the root url, at that time photo was already uploaded... The problem is only in new post and editing post but updating profile picture and adding profile picture has no error. I have uploaded photo using `simple_form`. What am I missing, please help me to solve the problem. [This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btxrA.png) of error page after uploading photo.

While changing to cloudinary I have followed the following steps:

1. I added `cloudinary.yml` in `config/` directory
2. I included `cloudinary` in `photo_uploader.rb` and removed `storage :file`.
3. Finally, I added `cl` tag in front of `image_tag` and made `cl_image_tag`

The `photo_uploader.rb` file is:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  # storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

My post controller file is:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
    before_action :is_owner?, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
      @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').includes(:user, comments: :user).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    end

    def new
      @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
      @post = current_user.posts.create(post_params)
      if @post.valid?
        flash[:success] = "Your photo has been successfully posted!"
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Woops! Looks like there has been an error!"
        render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    def edit
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @post.update(post_params)
      if @post.valid?
        flash[:success] = "Your post has been successfully updated!"
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Woops! Looks like there has been an error!"
        render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @post.destroy
      flash[:success] = "The post was successfully deleted!"
      redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def is_owner?
      redirect_to root_path if Post.find(params[:id]).user != current_user
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :photo, :description)
    end
end
```

The main problem is that `else` statement of `create model` is executed instead of `valid`.
How can I solve this please help me...

Comment: What's the validation error on `@post`? Log/Alert `@post.errors.full_messages`?

Comment: The error after uploading photo is :
`Woops! Looks like there has been an error!`

Comment: That's the not the validation error, but the hard coded error message. Looking at your screenshot, you forgot to upload the photo?

Comment: The error arises after uploading photo. I actually had uploaded photo. When I select a photo and write some description, I click post. The browser reloads after uploading photo showing that error message. But when I goto index page, that photo has been already uploaded:
My heroku link is http://madhav-instapost.herokuapp.com/. You can try here.

Comment: Changed `flash[:alert] = "Woops! Looks like there has been an error!"` to `flash[:alert]  = "#{@post.errors.full_messages.join(',')"` and see what's the exact error.

Comment: The error is `Photo can't be blank`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>      (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>     SQL (0.3ms)
>
> INSERT INTO "posts" ("photo", "description", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["photo", "Screenshot_from_2017-04-07_19-34-57_fxealu.png"], ["description", "asd"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", 2017-04-07 14:23:14 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-04-07 14:23:14 UTC]]
>     SQL (0.2ms)
>
> UPDATE "posts" SET "photo" = 'image/upload/v1491574997/Screenshot_from_2017-04-07_19-34-57_fxealu.png' WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  [["id", 4]]
>      (84.2ms)  commit transaction

You have programmed a post to be validate the presence of photo. Taking a look at the server log, it seems that the photo is updated after the post is validated.

Hence the flash message.

Remove the validation for the photo from your post.rb

It should look something like this.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord


belongs_to :user

has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

delegate :photo, :name, to: :user, prefix: true

validates :description, :user_id, presence: true

acts_as_votable

end
```

Hope this helped.

Note: This will allow the photo field to be empty.

Comment: Thank you brother! This solution solve my problem. But if we want to add photo as compulsory, what can I do?